# (datagrip) Database connection with multiple schemas

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I'd like to know if it's possible to manage multiple database schemas with just one connection in [datagrip].
Has anyone experience with that?

Comment: SO is a site for programming questions. This question is obviously off-topic.

Comment: At PostgreSQL part, there is an issue about this. [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2287](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2287)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on your database connection, and then click properties, you can choose schemas in schemas tab. Select your schemas, and then you must right click on your database connection again, and click synchronize. You will find your schemas.[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET93N.png)
[two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD9dK.png)

Answer (score -1):

Jan, if you mean multiple schemas in different DBs, then probably answer is no.
AFAIK, there is no IDE with such feature at all. If I'm wrong - please give a link.

If you want to work with several schemas in one DB - you can choose them in DB Properties/Schemas tab. It works fine.

Comment: You're so wrong. Navicat had that for ages. I really miss that feature in DataGrip.